# How to solve a large probability matrix of a Markov Chain with two servers in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, markov-chains

I'm trying to make a transition matrix of a Markov Chain with two servers, however, the initialisation seems to continuously go wrong. P[i][j] gives an error with undefined [i] and undefined [j], in the log it gives: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment. Somebody got any idea how to solve this?

```
import numpy as np

k = 1000
N = 15000
Lambda = 3
Mu1 = 196
Mu2 = 300
c = 2
P = []

def get_transition_matrix(
    c,
    N,
    Lambda,
    Mu1,
    Mu2
):

P[i][j] = np.zeros((N + 1, N + 1))

for i in range(N+1):
    for j in range(N+1):

        if i > 0 and 0 < j < N: 
            P[i][j] = 0

        if j == N and i == 0: 
            P[i][j] = 0.5

        if i == 0 and N > j > 0:
            P[i][j] = ((Mu1* P[0][j-1]) + (Mu2 * P[0][j+1]))/ (Lambda + Mu2)              

return P[i][j]

P[i][j] = get_transition_matrix(c, N, Lambda, Mu1, Mu2)
print(P[i][j])
```

Comment: The error message is correct. `i` and `j` are both undefined in the first line of your function. You probably wanted to write `P = np.zeros((N + 1, N + 1))`

Comment: Variable and functions names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.